# Android : stop and play sound on button click

Tags: android, audio, media-player, game-engine

I want to play a sound on button click in game.
I can easily do this using following code

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
mp.start();
```

Issue is, my clicking rate is faster then playing duration of my sound clip.
How do I stop it and play again on my second or third click and so on.

I want to match sound play to match my clicking rate.

Thanks
Abhinav Tyagi

Comment: `mp.pause()` and `mp.start()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should use `MediaPlayer` only for large files, like music. For playing sound effects, `SoundPool` is the way to go.

An excellent tutorial on playing back media is available [HERE](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html).

On the click of your button, call `soundPool.stop()` and `soundPool.play()` immediately in sequence to stop and start your audio playback.

Comment: soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener() requires API level 8+. I am targeting API level 3 and above.
Can I use it without this listener?

Comment: Just tried with out above listener and its working as required.
Thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 0):

You can call MediaPlayer.Stop to stop it playing sounds. You can also call MediaPlayer.Reset to return it to the Idle state.

Comment: I had already tried these... did not worked for me.
Above post by Vinay was what I wanted.
Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mplayer;

public void startPlay(View view) {
    mplayer.start();
}

public void stopPlay(View view) {
    mplayer.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.laugh);
}
```

}